# Is over provisioning on SSD just another partition or unreserved space and can it be alongside a dual boot partition OS setup?

Tags: windows, macos, ubuntu, partitioning, ssd

I have a few machines I'd want to dual boot different OSs with but also maximise the lifetime of the SSD fitted to them.

I am aware that over-provisioning can help maximise the life of the SSD as it provides space for the SSD to conduct its internal housekeeping.

What is over-provisioning *in terms of what space is reserved on the SSD*? Is it just creating another (physical type) standard partition? And is it possible to also setup a partitioned dual boot a machine (using the standard procedure) using an over-provisioned SSD?

**My setups**

(If this helps you to answer)

Although specific hardware listed here, however note that the over-provisioning concept is general among SSDs I believe, not just Samsung, for example, Kingston too: [How do I calculate an over or under-provisioning amount of space for my SSD?](https://superuser.com/questions/546548/how-do-i-calculate-an-over-or-under-provisioning-amount-of-space-for-my-ssd)

I have:

- A 2010 MacBookPro with a 512Gb Samsung 840 Pro SSD I fitted myself. This machine is dual boot Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks (384Gb partition) and Windows 7 Pro 64bit (via Bootcamp), (128Gb partition).
- A Lenovo X201S Thinkpad with 256Gb Samsung 840 Pro SSD I fitted myself. This machine is currently single boot Windows 8 Pro 64bit and I intend to dual boot it with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, say W8: 128Gb Ubuntu: 32Gb and a 64Gb shared partition.

Assuming that over-provisioning is creating a partition, or at least, just allocating unreserved space, then presumably I should have at least 3 physical type partitions available to support dual boot. (4 physical partitions is supported by a standard boot-loader, though a partition can contain multiple *logical* partitions). Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overprovisioning is just unreserved space. This according to Samsung who I have contacted on 2 separate occasions. Their Samsung Magician software contains an overprovisioning feature. I am informed that this software issues no vendor unique/specific commands to the drive.

Here is my answer to setting up overprovisioning with a dual-boot system:
https://askubuntu.com/a/563297/7072